# Transfer files from a USB thumb drive to iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, usb

What is the easiest way to transfer files from a USB thumb drive to an iOS device?

My current approach is to copy files to a Mac then airdrop the files. But this is unacceptable - my MacBook Pro is too large/heavy a device to take with me when I don’t use it for any other purpose.

Perhaps a cheap Android phone how would that work in practice? Any other suggestions?

Comment: What’s the type of files you are looking to transfer?

Comment: Are you the person who supplies the thumb drive? If yes, there are thumb drives that connect to iOS with an App.

Comment: @NimeshNeema various different kinds of document. I do theatre work and a typical project will have a few hundred documents of various types created by a dozen different people.

Comment: @KevinGrabher I avoid using thumb drives personally. They expensive and unreliable and easily lost. But other people like using them and often it's the only way I can get the file without having to pester them a few days in a row to email it to me. My goal here is to copy files off their thumb drive onto a cloud service provider (I'd be happy to switch to a different one if necessary to solve this issue).

Comment: There are products like the LaCie DJI Copilot (https://www.lacie.com/products/dji-copilot/), this one seems a bit overkill for your purpose. Maybe there are cheaper alternatives. But it seems like the kind of thing you are looking for.